# Spam Emails being triggered from my php site

Tags: php, spam-prevention

I have a straight forward website for my business which has a contact form(have fields Email, Mobile, Category & message) that on submission triggers an email to sender reading the Email id supplied.

***Issue that am facing:***
Junk/spam emails are triggered randomly.(as fix, i integrated a small text bases captcha that asks sum of two 1 digit number and if the answer supplied is correct, the for submits).

For first few days it was all fine, but then again spam mails started floating all around. I suppose this should be due to some crap bots by spammers but am just looking for a way i can stop this and make a fix.

PS: I have limited options for my UI as of now so Google captch/3rd party captcha would ruin my website's alignment. Yes its NOT a responsive website.

updating the code for more clarity.

```
<?php 
$sec1=rand(00,99);
$sec2=rand(01,10);
?>
<div id="leftpanel">
                <div align="justify" class="graypanel">
                <img src="images/computer.jpg"/>
                    <br><hr>
                    <form action="thankyou.php" method="POST" >
                    <fieldset><legend>Get in touch</legend>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="formdata">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="formdata">
                    <select name="business" class="formdata">
                        <option value="Business Not Disclosed">-------Select Business-------</option>
                        <option value="llp">LLP</option>
                        <option value="inc">Inc</option>
                        <option value="privateLimited">Private Limited</option>
                        <option value="publicLimited">Public Limited</option>
                        <option value="proprietor">Proprietor</option>
                        <option value="startup">Startup</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" name="ans" placeholder="Captcha : <?php echo $sec1; ?>+<?php echo $sec2; ?>=?"><br><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="trigger" value="true">
                        <input type="hidden" name="sec1" value="<?php echo $sec1; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="sec2" value="<?php echo $sec2; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can rename message field to smth else and make hidden field (or not visible textarea) named message. So bots will place input in this field and human users will not fiil in this field. Also you may check on server if e-mail domail exists and phone is valid.
But it works not for all bots, just makes their business a little bit harder.

Comment: @SergiyT. yes exactly, thats how its is now.
1) have hidden field to discourage bots
2) have logic check, it asks what is 2+3 and then the answere is saved as hidden field. on submission its being validated with submitted answer Vs the one on hidden field.

Comment: So you store valid answer as hidden field and check on submission on server side? Maybe output an image instead of numbers and ask user to type what they see in image, it is a lot harder to recognize image than text/number. You may than compare image id with tex input i.e. 1.jpg - square, 2.jpg - triangle etc. But it's making life harder for ordinary users also. Also there is a question what to do if spammers are real people, not a bots/scripts.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly why you should not be sending emails to user supplied email addresses. If you have an email form on your website, those emails must go only to yourself, not to an email address input through that form. You're just providing an anonymous email sending service.

There simply is no good fix. You could use a more effective CAPTCHA solution, but that devolves into a cat-and-mouse game between the CAPTCHA solution and the spammers employing ever better tricks to circumvent it. Simply. Don't. Do. It.

Comment: thanks, but again the spam isnt controlled. So in this case, my email box would be spammed. I just wanted to see if there is any robust solution to this. I even tried .htaccess modification to avoid bots but that didnt help either.

Comment: Yes, you may be receiving the spam in your inbox. But if that's the only place spammers will be able to send their message, the incentive is greatly reduced. But at the very least you won't be sending spam *from your domain* all over the internet, risking your domain being blacklisted by other providers. And again, you can just raise the bar for bots, e.g. using better CAPTCHAs; you will never be able to eliminate bots entirely.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, that makes sense. :)